# Game of Life in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.x, game-of-life

Conway's Game of Life is a common problem. I had to write a version of it to get my current C# job, so I thought it would be a nice way to get into Python (especially as the example in the book are a little too simple for my liking)

I've slightly abused the unit tests to print out the grids, normally I would not use a unit test as a functional test!

I'm not sure if I have grasped the "pythonic" principles so please let rip.

```
from random import randint


class Engine(object):

_grid = []

def __init__(self, rows, cols):
    self._rows = rows
    self._cols = cols

def seed(self, grid):
    """ Add a 'seed' grid; this allows adding known patterns
    :param grid: a 2 dimensional list containing only 1 or 0
    :return: null
    """
    self._grid = grid
    return

def generate(self):
    """ Using an existing 'seed' grid, follow the rules to change the
    values in the list
    :return: a 2 dimensional list containing only 1 or 0
    """

    # NB: if the system was not set up with a 'seed' pattern, generate one.
    if len(self._grid) == 0:
        self._grid = [[randint(0, 1) for row in range(self._rows)]
                     for col in range(self._cols)]

    generated = [[0 for row in range(self._rows)]
                 for col in range(self._cols)]

    for y in range(self._cols):
        for x in range(self._rows):

            neighbours = self.__neighbourCount(x, y)

            # Handles
            #  Rule 1 - Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours
            #  dies, as if caused by under-population (by defaulting to 0)
            #  Rule 2 - Any live cell with two or three live neighbours
            #  lives on to the next generation.
            #  Rule 3 - Any live cell with more than three live neighbours
            #  dies, as if by overcrowding (by defaulting to 0)
            if ((self._grid[y][x] == 1) and
                    (neighbours == 2 or neighbours == 3)):
                generated[y][x] = 1

            # Rule 4 - Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours
            # becomes a live cell
            if self._grid[y][x] == 0 and neighbours == 3:
                generated[y][x] = 1

    self._grid = generated
    return generated

def __neighbourCount(self, x, y):
    """ Return the sum of the value of neighbours of a cell in the grid
    :param x: the X coordinate index of the cell
    :param y: the Y coordinate index of the cell
    :return:
    """
    count = 0
    for row in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for col in (-1, 0, 1):
            if (not row == col == 0 and
                (0 <= x + row < self._rows and
                 0 <= y + col < self._cols)):
                count += self._grid[(y + col) % self._cols][(x + row) % self._rows]

    return count
```

Unit tests:

```
from nose.tools import *
from GameOfLife.engine import Engine

def test_GenerateWithOscillatorSeed():

rows = 10
cols = 10
input = [[0 for row in range(rows)] for col in range(cols)]

input[2][1] = 1
input[2][2] = 1
input[2][3] = 1

expected = [[0 for row in range(rows)] for col in range(cols)]
expected[1][2] = 1
expected[2][2] = 1
expected[3][2] = 1

engine = Engine(rows, cols)
engine.seed(input)
actual = engine.generate()

print 'INPUT ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(input))
print ''
print 'EXPECTED ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(expected))
print ''
print 'ACTUAL ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(actual))

assert actual == expected

# engine.seed(actual)
regenerated = engine.generate()

print ''
print 'REGENERATED ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(regenerated))

assert regenerated == input


def test_GenerateWithPulsarSeed():

rows = 17
cols = 17
input = [[0 for row in range(rows)] for col in range(cols)]

input = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
         ]

engine = Engine(rows, cols)
engine.seed(input)
iteration1 = engine.generate()
iteration2 = engine.generate()
iteration3 = engine.generate()


print 'INPUT ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(input))
print ''
print 'ITERATION 1 ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(iteration1))
print ''
print 'ITERATION 2 ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(iteration2))
print ''
print 'ITERATION 3 ----------------------------------------------'
print(formatPrintOut(iteration3))
print ''
assert input == iteration3


def formatPrintOut(grid):
return '\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format('.' if item == 0 else 'X')
                           for item in row])
                  for row in grid])
```

Finally, output proving it is working:

> ```
>     PS C:> nosetests -a
> INPUT ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> EXPECTED ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> ACTUAL ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> REGENERATED ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
>       INPUT ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> ITERATION 1 ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   X   X   X   .   .   X   X   .   X   X   .   .   X   X   X   .
> .   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   .
> .   X   X   X   .   .   X   X   .   X   X   .   .   X   X   X   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> ITERATION 2 ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   X   X   .   X   X   .   X   X   .   X   X   X   .   .
> .   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   .
> .   .   X   X   X   .   X   X   .   X   X   .   X   X   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   X   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .   .   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> ITERATION 3 ----------------------------------------------
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   X   .   .   .   .   X   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   X   X   X   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
> .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
>
> .
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 2 tests in 0.082s
>
> OK
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Codereview! Just check your indentation, as indentation is significant in Python and yours is messed up (`class` needs indents after it) (hint: Control-k allows for easy indenting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice. There's really not a lot to complain about, but I'll focus on the "Python" stuff.

#### Important: You've got a bug

Have you tried instantiating two different boards at the same time? You've (probably accidently) declared `_grid = []` at the class level so <strike>all instances share the same grid state</strike> (edit: I don't think that's technically true, see final note); get rid of that line and instead in the constructor add `self._grid = []`.

#### Tweak the naming

Because Python is dynamically typed, you don't have types littering your code: great. But you don't have types which clarify otherwise slightly ambiguous variable names: groan.

What do I mean by slightly ambiguous? Look at the constructor. I see the arguments are `rows` and `cols`. What you mean is *number* of rows, but the name suggests that perhaps it could take an actual *collection* of rows. So to figure out which, I had to keep reading and see how it was used; wasn't too hard, but if you name the parameter `num_rows` the intent becomes more clear.

For similar reasons, the interface for `seed` is a bit unclear. It's really a setter for `_grid`, so I'd just call it `set_grid`. This then begs the question if you're relying on your client knowing too much about the internal representation of an `Engine` object's grid. Probably. But for a small program, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

#### On being Pythonic

This line right here tells me that you've totally gotten into the Python groove. Nice.

```
generated = [[0 for row in range(self._rows)]
                 for col in range(self._cols)]
```

In a list comprehension or for loop where the name of the iterated element isn't referenced, some people prefer to deemphasize the name *because* it isn't used. They'll write

```
[0 for _ in range(self.num_rows)]
```

rather than

```
[0 for row in range(self.num_rows)]
```

They'd argue that `row` doesn't add value for the reader. I'm not telling you to do this, but it's something to think about, and something you might see others do.

#### Returns

I've got one uncontroversial opinion and one possibly controversial opinion.

See the `return` statement at the end of `seed`? As an uncontroversial matter of good style, get rid of it. It's just not necessary.

See the `return` at the end of `generate` ... tough call. I'm not sure it belongs there. The FP-enthusiast in me likes it, the OOP-side of me thinks it doesn't belong. Because of the way you've written the rest of the class, I hesitantly conclude that you shouldn't return any value from `generate`. I don't know how strongly you feel about that--removing the return value certainly has a big impact on calling code. Think about it (or not! :D).

#### EDIT and Final note: C# --> Python

After looking at it some more, I think the class level _grid is indeed attached but unused, and your normal code works (but only if you call `seed` first). Bottom line, the object system works a lot differently in Python because you can attach a member to an instance at any time. You probably should only intentionally do this in the constructor, but you might unintentionally do it and then notice strange/bugged behavior.

Here's some code that might front-load some of the surprising behavior:

```
class Person(object):
    location = "France"  # class variable, is this meaningful?
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location  # assign to the instance, not the class
    def __str__(self):
        return "<Person %s, in %s>" % (self.name, self.location)
    def attach_age(self, age): # don't ever write stupid stuff like this
        self.age = age  # instance probably didn't have 'age' prior to this method call

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alice = Person("Alice", "USA")
    bob = Person("Bob", "Germany")
    dave = Person("Dave", "China")

    print alice
    print bob

    print Person.location  # no error, but what does this even mean?

    alice.age = 24  # don't do stuff like this on purpose
    dave.attach_age(42)  # you're in trouble

    print alice.age
    print dave.age
    print bob.age  # error; potentially surprising
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to review, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I did not realise that class level variables are static. That's a big difference, but, I should have realised that, when creating the instance of `Engine` did not require a `new`. It does still seem a little strange.
"Tweak the naming" - you are correct. Coming from a strongly typed background I do tend to rely on type as a hint.
"Returns" - a hangover from C#. Your first point is valid; your second is argueable. Single responsibility means "generate" should not display but maybe I should have used a getter for `_grid` for display purposes.

Comment: @scudsucker I have a love/hate relationship with Python's dynamic nature. I added an additional code example to illustrate a big difference between C# and Python.